# does the module have got code object attribute?

Tags: python

according to 
[explore to the code object](https://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects.html)

> function has  code object attribute for the code inside of it, and
>   the code object has  bytecode attribute. By executing the bytecode,
>   python execute the function code.

1. does module object also have got code object attribute for all the
   code inside?
2. whether python execute the code inside the module by executing the
   bytecode attribute of code object of the module.
3. If not, what is the operation done by python when instantiating the
   module object when we `import` the module

Comment: The yellow highlighted text looks like it might be a quote from somewhere. What's the source? Some of the wording in the quote and the questions below is unclear

Comment: The linked page never says "got"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython modules don't have a code object attached at runtime.  `*.pyc` files contain the bytecode for the module, but it is discarded after executing it at `import`, because after importing it is not needed any more.

Given it is the first import of a module, the runtime checks if there is an up to date cached bytecode file.  If there is, it is loaded and the code object is executed in the context of a new `module` object.  If there isn't, the source is compiled to bytecode, possibly written to a file, and executed in the context of a new `module` object.

So how to get at the bytecode of a module then?  If you have a bytecode file, you can unmarshal the bytecode from it.  Assuming we have a module which just contains `print('Hello, World!')`:

```
>>> data = open('__pycache__/test.cpython-35.pyc', 'rb').read()
>>> import imp
>>> data.startswith(imp.get_magic())
True
>>> import marshal
>>> marshal.loads(data[len(imp.get_magic())+8:])
<code object <module> at 0x7f47b4fb5b70, file "/home/bj/test.py", line 4>
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(marshal.loads(data[len(imp.get_magic())+8:]))
  4           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello, World!')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you just have the source code: `compile()` it:

```
>>> compile("print('Hello, World!')", '<input>', 'exec')
<code object <module> at 0x7f47b4fc0f60, file "<input>", line 1>
>>> dis.dis(compile("print('Hello, World!')", '<input>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello, World!')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE       13 RETURN_VALUE
```